# About the usage of the Last will and testament message in MQTT

Tags: mqtt

In my case, I use the last will message of **MQTT** to notify that some clients disconnect unexpectedly, such as the listening topic is "*status*".

My question is that when one client is connected to the brokerA, then disconnect unexpectedly from the brokerA, but it reconnects again to the brokerA, at the time, could there be one "last message" sent to the "status" topic?

Another question is that: when the last will message could be sent after one client disconnected from the broker unexpectedly.

Comment: You question is unclear, please consider improve the question making it more answerable!

Answer (score 0):

There is a really good description of the LWT (Last Will and Testement) here:

http://www.hivemq.com/mqtt-essentials-part-9-last-will-and-testament/

But the simple version is as follows:

The broker will only deliver the LWT message under the following circumstances are met:

- An I/O error or network failure is detected by the server.
- The client fails to communicate within the Keep Alive time.
- The client closes the network connection without sending a DISCONNECT
  packet first.
- The server closes the network connection because of a protocol error.

Comment: Either I'm misunderstanding your final statement, or I think it is wrong. I presume it's the former, could you explain a bit more what you mean?

Comment: I was always under the impression that for a suitably long keepAlive, if the client crashes and restarts with the same client ID you shouldn't see a LWT. Could be wrong, it's been a while since I've tried it

Comment: In that case it depends on whether the broker detects the socket closing or not. Not something that you could rely on I don't think.